# Is there a way to map a single callback route to multiple strategies using Omniauth?

Tags: omniauth

I am porting an existing SAML application to use Rails. The current implementation uses a single callback endpoint, and distinguishes between multiple callers via the Issuer SAML tag.

In this new application I would like to use a single callback endpoint, `/saml`, for backwards compatibility, but dynamically choose the OmniAuth strategy. That would allow me to select a different `idp_cert` and `attribute_statements` depending on the calling user.

Is this possible to do, or is there another (better) way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution. The provider configuration can be setup dynamically, before the request or callback phase, per the OmniAuth wiki: https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Setup-Phase